# Running angular.js app from network folder

Tags: angularjs, routes, network-share

I'm stuck with Internet Explorer 8 and working in a large corporate environment.  I have a simple angular.js app with a few routes, one controller, and one view.  When I run it off my C:\ drive, it prompts me to "Allow Blocked Content..." but when I try to run it from a network location like \server\share\folder\ it doesn't prompt me at all and angular doesn't even handle my route.  If I manually add the default route of #/ to the URL, IE says, "Windows cannot find..." followed by my URL.

There are no errors in the console, so I'm at a loss as to how to trouble-shoot this.  Is there an easy way to make this work?

Comment: all resources ie css , script,image etc from same domain and same port?

Comment: Had to double-check that one.  Yes, everything is loading using relative URLs.  jQuery, bootstrap, angular (css and script files).  That's it.